# Retaining meta-tags in AWS S3 upon deployments by Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, metadata, aws-codepipeline

I have a serverless website on AWS with the HTML, JS, CSS files in an S3 bucket - to optimize performance most of these files are GZIP compressed and marked with `content-encoding` `gzip` in the *Properties* > *Metadata*

I recently create a `Code Pipeline` to deploy any changes to `s3` bucket... So instead of manually replacing the s3 bucket from my local folder - I update my repo in `CodeCommit` (AWS's flavored Git) and it deploys it to my `S3` bucket... no issues with the pipeline at all

**The issue I am facing**: 
As a result of code pipeline firing, when a new file replaces an existing file in s3, it removes the meta-tags that I had put there (on the previous file)... especially the `content-encoding : gzip` meta-tags... which messes up my website !!!

What would be the best way to preserve any/all meta-tags when code-pipeline deploys stuff to s3?

**Ideally, I would like to avoid *(if possible)*** using CloudFront - or writing a Lambda function which scans my repo and adds a gzip tag to all HTML, CSS, JS etc.

Comment: No answer on this...... :(

Comment: I am interested in this because I'd like to NOT see the aws meta tags of the build end up in public hands:  User defined x-amz-meta-codebuild-buildarn arn:aws:codebuild:xxxxx:123456789:build/myfirstbuildeverlookeveryone:5194f530-9505-4fb2-8034-c3cb553e4643